Excel VBA CheckBox1_Click() Looping
The below code goes into an endless loop if you click on checkbox1.  Any idea why?  If I step through the code, it alternatively jumps through each of the two TextBox1.value=... statements.  It does not visibly update the check box.
    
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Select Case CheckBox1
        Case True
            CheckBox1 = False
            TextBox1.value = ""
        Case False
            CheckBox1 = True
            TextBox1.value = InputBox("What order do you want " & CheckBox1.Caption & " to be sorted in? ie 1, 2, 3...", "Sort Order")
    End Select
    
End Sub



Sorry,  this is Excel VBA

I presume you've positioned the checkbox within a userform. When you change the value of the checkbox, the event is triggered again resulting in an endless loop.. Therefore, you need to suppress the events in that userform
Taken from here you could do it like that
Option Explicit
Public EnableEvents As Boolean
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Not EnableEvents Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    EnableEvents = False
    Select Case CheckBox1
        Case True
            CheckBox1 = False
            TextBox1.Value = ""
        Case False
            CheckBox1 = True
            TextBox1.Value = InputBox("What order do you want " & CheckBox1.Caption & " to be sorted in? ie 1, 2, 3...", "Sort Order")
    End Select
    EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub

The code will run, but it doesn't make much sense, as it will automatically reset the checkbox to its initialized value. So, it will always remain unchecked if you initialized the checkbox with that value.
